# Block any memory or DLL file injection to a specific application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How do block any memory or DLL file injection in a specific application for anti-cheat purposes?

If a block is not possible I want at least to detect if there has been a memory injection. I've read and googled a lot about this issue, and I can't find a legitimate method to use.

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to detect memory injections perfectly. Your code will likely be user-mode, and drivers can be used to circumvent your user-mode code. You'll also be fighting with the users' antivirus software.

Anti-cheat done locally is a form of [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management); don't do this. Do this server-side instead.